# TFS automatic order work items by iteration in a view

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

One thing I find myself frequently doing in TFS 2015 is re-ordering items in the Backlog view to make sure they follow the order of the assigned iterations. It's easy for them to get out of order because different Teams use different filters and ordering something in one team view may put it out of order in another team view. Also depending on how you create/add a work item it may get automatically placed at the bottom or somewhere else.

Is anyone aware of any techniques for maintaining this order short of dragging items around in the Backlog view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the work items is ordered by `Backlog priority`(Scrum template) or `stack rank`(Agile and CMMI templates ). Please see [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/05/14/behind-the-scenes-the-backlog-priority-or-stack-rank-field/) for details.

To order the work items in backlog you can refer to [Backlog priority or stack rank order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/backlogs-overview?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#backlog-priority-or-stack-rank-order) for details.

> The sequence of items on each backlog is determined according to where
>   you have [added the items or moved the items on the page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/create-your-backlog?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#move-items-priority-order). As you
>   drag and drop items within the backlog list, a background process
>   updates the [Stack Rank (Agile and CMMI processes)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/planning-ranking-priorities?view=vsts) or Backlog
>   Priority (Scrum process) fields. These fields are used by the system
>   to track the relative ranking of items on the product, feature, epic,
>   or other portfolio backlog. By default, these fields don't appear on
>   the work item form.

So, you can multiple select the items and change the order or export a query containing the backlog items, update either the `Backlog Priority` or `Stack Rank` fields, and then publish your changes back to TFS.

Comment: Thanks. I understand how the ranking in the backlog view works. My issue is that this manually ordered backlog often gets out of sync with the iterations, which have a defined chronology and dates. I'm looking for an easier way to keep them in sync.

Comment: Unfortunately no way to sync for now, based on current logic you have to manually update the order...